# Interact with a JavaScript page in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, web-scraping

This is an example page:

http://scores.covers.com/basketball-scores-matchups.aspx?t=0

Let's say that I want to download the pages that are behind the "Boxscore" link for a range of dates. The date is changed using JavaScript. How do I do emulate clicking on next and previous dates and get the contents of the refreshed boxscore link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially want to do screen scraping. You want to access the output of a web page through C#. There are many libraries that allow you to do this. The best other use case for the tool you want is writing User interface tests, and many UI test frameworks support it.

Take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.org/), for example. You can use it to "emulate" user behavior on a web page.
Another candidate would be [Telerik's testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/webaii-framework-features.aspx) (disclaimer: I work for Telerik)

Answer (score 0):

In the handler response, you are getting boxscore link in gamehtml. In handler code, you can extract the link using regular expression and download it using httpwebrequest.

OR

try [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by handler response. Could you elaborate please?